# Understanding this date format - Redtail

Tags: date, timestamp, timezone-offset

What date format is this: `-147114000000-0700`. It is supposed to be `05/04/1965`.

The first term looks like a unix timestamp. But then why would we need the second term?

I am using [Redtail's api](https://help.redtailtechnology.com/hc/en-us/articles/203964470-Contact-By-ContactID-Methods-contacts-contactid-), but they provide negligible documentation on this. They are sending over a date looking like `"/Date(-147114000000-0700)/"`. I have never seen this format before. Ignoring all the useless text, we get `-147114000000-0700`, still leaving me puzzled.

Comment: Do you know which date this represents? Does it match the unix timestamp portion? `-0700` is probably a timezone.

Comment: `-0700` is an UTC offset: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Comment: @Blorgbeard Actually, a timezone is *the set of all offsets that a region had, has and will have during its history*, while the offset is just *the difference from UTC* (check the section **TimeZone != Offset** in the [timezone tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)). There can be [more than one timezone that uses the same offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC.E2.88.9207:00.2C_T).

Comment: Yeah, my terminology was very sloppy there.

Comment: Considering the Unix timestamp is already UTC based, what is the purpose of the UTC offset?

Comment: @Elliot The same unix timestamp can represent different dates and times in different parts of the world, so the offset is a way to get specific values, like explained in my answer below. The timestamp in question (`-147114000000`) can be either May 4th or 3rd, depending on the timezone, for example - the offset helps you to disambiguate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-147114000000` value is a unix timestamp in milliseconds: it represents the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (which is `1970-01-01T00:00Z` or **January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at midnight in UTC**).

As the number `-147114000000` is negative, it represents a date **before** epoch. In this case, `1965-05-04T07:00:00Z` (or **May 4<sup>th</sup> 1965 at 7 AM in UTC**).

`-0700` is an [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset): it represents the difference from UTC. In this case, 7 hours behind UTC, which results in `1965-05-04T00:00-07:00` (or **May 4<sup>th</sup> 1965 at midnight in `-07:00` offset**). *Note that an offset can be written as `-07:00`, `-0700` or `-07`*.

But keep in mind that this same value can represent a different date and time in each timezone. For example, in [`Pacific/Honolulu` timezone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/honolulu) (that uses the `-10:00` offset [since 1947](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/honolulu?year=1940)), the same timestamp corresponds to `1965-05-03T21:00-10:00` (**May 3<sup>rd</sup> 1965 at 9 PM, in offset `-10:00`**). So the corresponding date and time will depend on what timezone you convert this to.

That being said, probably the purpose of having the offset is just to tell you what's the offset that the date/time refers to, so it prevents you from converting to a different offset (where you can get different values for local date and time).

---

Just reminding that `-0700` is not a timezone, it's just an offset. Actually, a timezone is *the set of all offsets that a region had, has and will have during its history*, while the offset is just *the difference from UTC* (check the section **TimeZone != Offset** in the [timezone tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)). There can be [more than one timezone that uses the same offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC.E2.88.9207:00.2C_T), so you can't really say in what timezone this is in.